# How can i add a hash in my $jsOptions on Yii2

Tags: yii2

I want hashing my assets on yii2, but i can´t find the way to do it, can you help me please?

Exactly in this parte of my AppAsset.php

```
public $jsOptions = [
    'defer' => 'defer',
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

**If I understand what you mean correctly,**

```
// code ...
public $js = [
    ['js/first.js','integrity' => '{hash}'],
    ['js/second.js','integrity' => '{hash2}'],
];
public $jsOptions = [
    'crossorigin' => 'anonymous',
     // 'async' => 'async',  {or defer}
];
// code ...
```

**If you use Hash in jsOptions, it is used for all JS files:**

```
public $js = [
    'js/first.js',
    'js/second.js',
];
public $jsOptions = [
    'integrity' => '{hash}';
    'crossorigin' => 'anonymous',
];
```

For `sha256`, `sha384`, `sha512` algorithms